# date range filtering issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to filtering the date between two textbox, my problem is when I pick the date on the second box, it  doesnt include the date that i choose.

the code  for textbox

```
            <label for="from">From</label>

            <input type="text" id="from"  />

            <label for="to">To</label>

            <input type="text" id="to" />
```

for script the datepicker

```
         //function for datepicker and date range
     $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate  );
        }
    });
  });
```

updated

```
   $from = new Date(Date.parse($("#from").datepicker('getDate')));
   $to = new Date(Date.parse($("#to").datepicker('getDate')));
```

this is how it defined

Comment: Where are `$from` and `$to` defined? COuld you assemble a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just access the value directly:

```
 if ($("#from").val()) {

     $filter.push({field: "DateEnrolled", operator: ">=", value: $("#from").val()});
 }

 if ($("#to").val()) {
     $filter.push({field: "DateEnrolled", operator: "<=", value: $("#to").val()});
 }
```